# chrome.identity.getAuthToken isn't able to store token when user disables Syncing

Tags: google-chrome-extension, oauth-2.0

I'm developing a Chrome Extension to process user's emails. I'm using chrome.identity.getAuthToken to prompt the user for login and permissions.

The issue is when the user doesn't turn on Syncing, my extension keeps asking for the user to login every time the user interacts with it.

I checked chrome://identity-internals/, no token for my extension is stored there.

Everything works as expected when the user turns on syncing.

What should I do for the extension to work regardless of the sycn settings?

Comment: Have you checked the solution in this [SE post](https://superuser.com/questions/845000/how-can-i-sign-in-to-chrome-but-not-immediately-sync-everything)?

Comment: Sounds like a bug or undocumented limitation. Can you raise an issue at https://crbug.com and post a link here?